# Link Android application with contacts/phonebook programmatically

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I'm currently writing an App which allows to extend the standart Android contacts / phonebook. The user can add some informations / content associated with a specific contact. I want the standart phonebook to show an link to my application on every contact which has additional data in my application. For example **WhatsApp** is able to do so. If somebody from you phonebook has an WhatsApp account the phonebook displays a small WhatsApp icon next to the contact. If you hit the icon WhatsApp starts automatically a chat with this specific person.

My question is now how this can be achieved ? If someone can point me in the right direction it would be great.

I guess it must be done somehow with an `ContentProvider`. I already specified an `ContentProvider` but I don't know how to tell the Contacts app that this one exist or where I need to register this provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Contacts Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html).  Class `ContactsContract.Contacts` provide access to all the contacts available in android mobile.

You need to have Read contacts permission in your app manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Refer following Android developer site.
http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/index.html

Source code can be downloaded at http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/ContactsList.zip

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jeno. I know that this allows my app to read the Contacts from the phone, but I want to associate my app with an specific entry in the Contacts app. If you open the Contacts app I want it to display the icon of my app next to the specific contact (like Whatsapp does). And I want to allow the user to directy open my app with this specific contact (like WhatsApp does). How can I achive this ?

Comment: It turned out that this was the right place look and that I was looking to ContactsContract.RawContacts and their aggregation. thanks Jeno

Comment: @Westranger have you find any solution?if so then let me know