# Link android contacts with registered user on app

Tags: android

I'm new to Android and connected few dots for my problem but stuck with one point.

**Goal**: Like WhatsApp icon displayed in contact that are registered user of WhatsApp. I want to do the same for my app's registered user.

**What I did so far**: I created [sync adapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/) to run contact sync in background.

Now I want to do something like this.

```
cursor start [read android contact]
    // api calls
    if(user-registered-with-app){
        // attach my app's userId with android contact and save the contact
    }
cursor end
```

Is it the correct way to link my app's user to android contacts?

I've read following questions but I didn't understand it properly.

[Link Android application with contacts/phonebook programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816035/link-android-application-with-contacts-phonebook-programatically)

[Android check contacts if they are registered in an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29070155/android-check-contacts-if-they-are-registered-in-an-app)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27816205/10182897 this one helps you to access contacts to your application and https://stackoverflow.com/a/29070320/10182897 this one i think it sends the contact list to server database and confirm which users are register

Comment: check these two tutorials: http://blog.udinic.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/ http://blog.udinic.com/2013/07/24/write-your-own-android-sync-adapter